# Can't catch exception in C# with PdfMetamorphosis

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

When convert docx into pdf using PdfMetamorphosis, there is a warning:

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The code is here:

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(dataFolder, "*.docx");

    foreach (string fileName in files)
    {
        try
        {
            //Console.ReadKey();
            SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis p = new SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis();

            if (p != null)
            {
                string docxPath = fileName;
                string pdfPath = Path.ChangeExtension(docxPath, ".pdf");


                // Convert DOCX file to PDF file 
                int result = p.DocxToPdfConvertFile(docxPath, pdfPath);

                if (result == 0)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(fileName + "Conversion succeeded!");
                    //Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(fileName + "Conversion failed!");
                    //Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            continue;
        }

    }
```

**The exception occurred in "int result = p.DocxToPdfConvertFile(docxPath, pdfPath);"** and the code crashed.  I want to catch the exception, ignore it and continue the loop.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvSmp.jpg)

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you trying to fix the cause of exception or just catch it?

Comment: I just want to catch it and stop my code from crash.

Comment: You should not mention continue keyword in catch block instead of Exception keyword. And this is a ArgumentOutOfRangeException so without throwing or log the exception you cannot continue. So try like this catch (Exception e ){ throw e.message.tostring();  }

Comment: Are you sure, that your code is crashing? Maybe it is just VS showing you an exception when it rised, but what will happend if you just press `F5`? Btw, @MdAslam I doubt that `throw e.message.tostring();` will ever compile.

Comment: what about this code (putting @ for filename )?  string docxPath = @fileName;
                string pdfPath = Path.ChangeExtension(docxPath, ".pdf");

Comment: @MdAslam, `@` in variables names only usefull, when the name of variable is a reserverd word (like `@ref`) or start with not allowed symbol (like `@1st`) so, no, this code will not help.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? (I cannot open images on this network). 1. Is the exception being thrown from inside the `try`? 2. Have you tried `Clean Solution` and `Build Solution` in case you are running old code?

Comment: throw e.message.tostring(); cannot compile.

Comment: @MdAslam doesn't work.

Comment: @MichalCiechan I debug it step by step to find it occurred inside the try

Comment: @vasily.sib I continue execution and the code stopped.

Comment: then, can you try catch exactly this exception, but without continue: `try { ... } catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }`

Comment: Could it be that one of those methods is farming work off to a custom background thread, which is throwing an exception and bringing the process down? When the exception is thrown can you see what thread you are on. Also what is the call stack?

Comment: @MichalCiechan The call stack is external code

Comment: It may be worth enabling ExternalCode in debug options, and viewing the stack trace. Might tell you some more info... It could be happening on a background thread and therefore bringing your process down.